# Saving data to cache and retrieving it

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been using the following cache class

[Cache class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181273/how-can-i-create-a-class-that-caches-objects)

I have the following in my code, first is the sql statement

```
SELECT Id, AmbitiousDescription from [User].[Ambitious_Description]
```

Next is the part when I read it in to a list

```
var ambition = sqlCon.Read().ToList();
```

I then save it to the cache, which saves me doing multiple trips to the database.

```
Cache.CacheExtension.SaveTocache("ambition", ambition, new DateTime(1));
```

At the top of this method I check to see if its in the cache as shown here

```
 if (Cache.CacheExtension.IsIncache("ambition"))
 {
    var listAmbition = new SelectList(Cache.CacheExtension.GetFromCache("ambition"), "1", "AmbitiousDescription");
 }
 else
 {
   // otherwise get it from the database
 }
```

I currently get a red error under the word GetFromCache which reads

[image]

I'm not 100% what the syntax would be to retrieve it back from the cache so if anyone can help I'd appreciate it.

**Update**

After comments from Stephen I decided to create a class called AmbitionDetails as shown here:

```
 public class AmbitionDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I then populate this by doing the following, first I read the results then I use linq to populate the list ambitionDetails

```
 // Read all the data from the query multiple
    var ambition = sqlCon.Read().ToList();

    var ambitionDetails = ambition.Select(item => new AmbitionDetails
    {
       Id = item.Id,
       Description = item.AmbitiousDescription
    }).ToList();
```

I then save this in the cache as shown here:

```
Cache.CacheExtension.SaveTocache("ambition", ambitionDetails, new DateTime(1));
```

I then try to retrieve this from the cache as shown here here:

```
var listAmbition = new SelectList(Cache.CacheExtension.GetFromCache<List<AmbitionDetails>>("ambition"));

            model.ListAmbitious = new List<SelectListItem>();

            model.ListAmbitious.AddRange(
                    listAmbition.Select(
                        item => new SelectListItem { Text = item.Text, Value = item.Value.ToString() }));
```

But I get a null exception error on the item => new SelectListItem, but when I put a break point on the

```
 var listAmbition;
```

and expand it to see the results the text is

```
"ApplicationName.Shared.Models.AmbitionDetails"
```

And the value is null

Which I'm not sure what's going wrong here?

Comment: You would need to cast the value. What is the type you are saving to cache - `List<?>`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I haven't given it a type I'm currently using 

var ambition = sqlCon.Read().ToList();

Comment: Your `GetFromCache<T>` method is returning `T`. `The first parameter of the `SelectList` constructor expects `IEnumerable<T>` You will need to specify the return type e.g `GetFromCache<List<yourType>>("ambition")`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I can't save the select list item in the cache because that has caused issue in the past, i.e remember previously selected values which I believe we spoke about on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28980653/mvc-dropdown-remembers-previous-selected-value-from-previous-record

Comment: No you should not save the `SelectList`, but you do need to specify the type of object in the list (otherwise your only returning `class` (as in `where T : class`).  Do you have a type class named `Ambition` with properties `Id` and `Description`? - or some base class that has an `int` and `string` property that you can use to hold the properties of the object?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have created a new class, and im using that as the type, I have updated the question as I'm still getting an error when using the List<className> as a type for the cache, I want to retrieve it from the Cache and build the ListAmbition which is a SelectListItem

Comment: It could be just `model.ListAmbitious = new SelectList(Cache.CacheExtension.GetFromCache<List<AmbitionDetails>>("ambition"), "Id", "Description");` (no need to create a `SelectList` and then create another one from it) The problem is that you current code does not specify the `Value` and `Text` properties in the constructor so each item would just be the string "YourAssembly.AmbitionDetails" which does not have properties `Text` and `Value`

Comment: Also from your previous question, you appear to be storing a number of collections in cache for generating various select lists. A simple class (say) `public class Item() { public int ID { get; set; } public string Name { get; set; }}` might be more easier rather than creating multiple classes

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've just tried what you suggested in your previous comment and the error im now getting is cannot convert source type System.Web.Mvc.SelectList to target type System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>

Comment: Is the model property `ListAmbitious` typeof `SelectList` (or typeof `List<SelectListItem>`)? - it needs to be the `SelectList`

Comment: @StephenMuecke its the following      public List<SelectListItem> ListAmbitious { get; set; }

Comment: If you change it to `public SelectList ListAmbitious { get; set; }` it should work fine.

Comment: @StephenMuecke   That solved the issue in regards to returning it from the cache, but As I've now changed it from SelectListItem to SelectList I can't populate it after call the DB this is what I'm currently using but it errors;   model.ListAmbitious.AddRange(
                           ambition.Select(
                               item => new SelectListItem { Text = item.AmbitiousDescription, Value = item.Id.ToString() }));

Comment: Not really clear why you would need to use `AddRange` . Either you get the collection from cache **or** from the database if it does not exist in the cache (e.g. expired), but if you want it to be `List<SelectListItem>` then - `var listAmbition = Cache.CacheExtension.GetFromCache<List<AmbitionDetails>>("ambition"); model.ListAmbitious.AddRange(listAmbition.Select(item => new SelectListItem { Text = item.Description , Value = item.Id.ToString() }));`